# Get Clean Image of a Windows Form

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I would like to know how to get a image/screenshot of a Windows Form in .NET while it is running **as it would have been seen in the designer/when it is first opened**, i.e. without any text in controls etc. Basically I would like an image of the form as it's clean copy. Is there a way to do this?

I thought that a way may be to get an image of the form as soon as it is opened, but the situation I have is that I don't know what forms there will be in the main application (I am developing a class library), and as far as I know, there isn't a global form load event or something to solve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the problem.  Why don't you just make a screenshot while it is loaded in the designer?  The Shown event is the first runtime event.

Comment: I need to make the screenshot programmatically when a user clicks a button on a form. But I don't want to have any text the user may have entered in the various form controls to show up in the screenshot. I also don't know what form this will be on, so I can't subscribe to the Shown or Load event.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no way. Your best bet is to use print screen